Ping Identity -> integrations -> provisioning -> SCIM - auth fails
New to Ping, and trying to set SCIM integration to my app.
This one SEEMS to make most sense, as my app only takes a token, but it fails - the API call is redirected to an interactive login screen.Auth type
A Postman call with header does work: [key] Authorization [value] Basic Encoded-Token==
Similar setting in Okta towards my app does work.
What am I missing that might be Ping-specific?
Thanks!
